# How to fix 'ibatis binding exception' when testing mybatis functionality in Springboot?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm trying to make a unit test for Mybatis in SpringBoot. I keep getting ibatis.binding.bindingException whenever I try to execute a query defined in the mapper.xml.

My test code is stored in src/test/java/service with name UserServiceImplTest.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceImplTest {


    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    public void getUserByIdAndEmail() throws SQLException {
        User user = userDao.getUserByIdAndEmail("admin", "admin@sample.com");
        assertThat(user.getUser_email()).isEqualTo("admin@sample.com");
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public class UserDao implements UserDaoMapper{  
    @Autowired  
    private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession;

    public User getUserByIdAndEmail(String user_id, String user_email) {
        UserDaoMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(UserDaoMapper.class);
        return mapper.getUserByIdAndEmail(user_id, user_email);
    }   
}
```

SqlSessionTemplate, SqlSessionFactory and Datasource beans are defined in a java file where there is @SpringBootApplication.

From

```
User user = userDao.getUserByIdAndEmail("admin", "admin@sample.com");
```

I was hoping at least to get null User, but when executing the method itself the error pops out. Below is the error log.

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.sampleProject.dao.UserDaoMapper.getUserByIdAndEmail

    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:227)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:49)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:65)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:58)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.getUserByIdAndEmail(Unknown Source)
    at com.sampleProject.dao.UserDao.getUserByIdAndEmail(UserDao.java:25)
    at com.sampleProject.dao.UserDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a267b137.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.sampleProject.dao.UserDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b41323d1.getUserByIdAndEmail(<generated>)
    at com.sampleProject.service.UserServiceImplTest.getUserByIdAndEmail(UserServiceImplTest.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, after creating a 'resources' directory under test and moving *mapper.xml files under the resources directly solved the problem. I guess the test class was not able to find mapper.xml files, causing a binding exception as a result.